# Need to iterate values in multi-dimensional array using LINQ JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq.js

I have created array like below,

```
arr =[ {uName:"2015", 1:100,2:10,3:0},{uName:"2011",1:10,2:2,3:19},{uName:"2015",1:10,2:0,3:20}],
```

Here, I need to select `arr[0][1]` and `arr[2][1]` where `uName is "2015"`.

Linq query is,

```
$.Enumerable.From(arr).Where(function(n){n.uName =="2015"}).Select(function(y){return y.1}).Sum()
```

Expected answer is:

```
arr[0][1] = 100, arr[2][1] = 10 (or) sum of these value 110 (arr[0][1] + arr[2][1])
```

Comment: That array declaration is not valid Javascript.

Comment: Yes Robby.I just given example mension that.

Comment: Adding "for example" to your question doesn't make it valid, _you_ make it valid by posting a good example that actually makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restructure your array, because that's not a valid javascript object. You cannot mix an object structure with an array structure.

```
var arr =[ {uName:"2015", num1: 100,num2: 10, num3: 0},
           {uName:"2011", num1: 10, num2: 2, num3: 19},
           {uName:"2015",num1: 10, num2: 0, num3: 20}];

var expected = $.Enumerable.From(arr).Where(
               function(x){return x.uName =="2015"}).Select(
               function(a){ return a.num1}).Sum();
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99eu7/37/

Comment: Thanks the post. Is there any possible to access element directly?

Comment: Yes there is, eg: arr[0].num1

Comment: Fine. solution was helped for me.